# How to run a command after receiving a mail with exim4?

Tags: shell, email, exim, command-line-interface

Where can I tell exim to run a shell/php command everytime a new mail has been delivered to a virtual mailbox. It does not matter to which user the mail is delivered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at `shadow_transport`.

For local deliveries (only), if delivery succeeds and the Transport references another Transport in its `shadow_transport` option, then that second transport will also be invoked.

You'd then have that second Transport be a `driver = pipe` transport.

Eg:

```
maildir_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  directory = ...blah blah whatever ...
  maildir_format
  # various other maildir extension options if needed
  shadow_transport = audit_delivery

audit_delivery:
  driver = pipe
  command = /some/path/to/some/command with some options
  user = audituser
  group = mail
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you apparently have a real user to deliver to, you probably want to look into using a `.forward` file, or possibly procmail if you want to get a bit fancier (such as if you only want to run the command for a subset of messages delivered to the user).

Comment: Unfortunately I am having a multi user/domain system via exim4/mysql/courier-imap I meant with local user, that this user is terminated in my system. But it should be called disjunct from the user recieving the mail.

Comment: "local user" has very specific meaning with MTAs, you might want to edit your question to say "virtual mailbox" if you're running that sort of system.

Comment: thx, I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way I found was creating a new router afterwards delivering to the local users containing:

```
runscript:
        driver = accept
        transport = run_script
        unseen
        no_expn
        no_verify
```

So, the mail is still handeld the way it should be and my script is running, with the right transport f.e.:

```
run_script:
        debug_print = "T: run_script for $local_part@$domain"
        driver = pipe
        path = "<path>"
        command = "<command to be run>"
```